# The xxx service failed to start due to the following error: 1053 in Docker

Tags: c#, .net, docker, .net-core, docker-for-windows

I am trying to start a Windows-Service in a Windows-based Docker-container with the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/insider:10.0.17763.107

COPY ["Install/", "C:/Service/Name/"]

USER ContainerAdministrator

RUN powershell New-Service -Name "Name" -BinaryPathName "C:\Service\Name\Name.exe"
```

When trying to start the service with `Start-Service Name` it takes some time and then the services stops. In the eventlog I have found the following error:

```
    The Name service failed to start due to the following error:1053
```

CreateHostBuilder:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
       Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .ConfigureLogging((hostingcontext, logging) =>
           {
               logging.ClearProviders();
               logging.AddConsole();
               logging.AddEventLog();
               logging.AddConfiguration(hostingcontext.Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
           }).ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
           {
               string pathToExe = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;
               string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathToExe);
               config.SetBasePath(dir);
           })
           .UseWindowsService()
           .ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices);
```

When installing the service on my local machine it works as it should.

Comment: Try starting it as a console app first. 1053 is "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion", and a very common cause for this is the service registering itself with the Service Control Manager under a different name than was used in `New-Service` (if the names don't match, the SCM can't "see" the service and thus declares it dead). This in turn could happen if the service can't read its configuration correctly (or the configuration is just wrong). It's very hard to troubleshoot this without some kind of service-specific logging or debugging, though.

Comment: The service starts and does what it should, but after some time it fails. What could be interesting from the logs: `The description for Event ID '<id>' in Source 'EventSystem' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:'86400', 'SuppressDuplicateDuration', 'Software\Microsoft\EventSystem\EventLog' The User Profile Service has stopped.  `

Comment: That message is usually not *that* interesting, even though it may look intimidating. The whole "The description for event yada yada" thing means the message DLL isn't registered, but this is harmless apart from seeing that boilerplate every time. The real message is still logged (in this case "The User Profile Service has stopped.", which shouldn't have anything to do with your service).

Comment: The service starts and does what it should, but somehow stays in the status Starting and therefore I get the error 1053. Do you have any ideas what the reason for staying in startup could be, even though it runs?

Comment: My working theory is still that the service reports itself to the Service Control Manager using a different name (that is, not the `"Name"` specified in `New-Service`), since that would cause exactly the symptoms described. However, I don't know enough about the MS code for service hosting to determine where *that* gets the service name from, so I don't know how to confirm or deny that. Take a closer look at what `ConfigureServices` does.

Comment: There's another thing where it might potentially falter: if it's running as a console app, or *thinks* it's running as one, it won't register with the SCM at all. Detecting if you're running as a service is not completely trivial, even though you wouldn't expect MS to get that wrong. :P

Comment: I tried it with a simple application that only logs something to the eventlog and it has the same behaviour, so also staying in the state Starting and then getting the 1053-error

Comment: @JeroenMostert Any ideas how to find out what name is used by the service to register itself to the service control manager?

Comment: Other than consulting the source of MS' stuff, no (I'm assuming they've open sourced it). Ultimately something somewhere calls `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler[Ex]`, and the first argument of that is the service name. If that function is not called, or called with the wrong argument, the SCM won't see the process as a service.

Comment: Regarding to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/database-of-installed-services) every service is in the service-database and has a registry-key at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
When using Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services' and searching for the service-name I can find it and all values are the same as on my local machine

Comment: Yes, those values are not relevant. If they were wrong, the process wouldn't start running in the first place. Instead it runs, but the process isn't recognized as hosting a service.

Comment: Thanks @JeroenMostert, solved the issue